# STM32F769 Erasing Block or Page Problem

Tags: stm32

I'm having an issue erasing pages or blocks of  STM32F769 flash. Reference manuel says that  The Flash memory erase operation can be performed at sector level, at bank level or on the whole Flash memory.
And as you know if we update any flash address , we have to erase all sector. 
In my project, I need to update and  save IP , Gateway and NetMask address(12 byte data) of my device. I am using single bank and the sector number is from 0 through 11. 
I need to use three flash address of same sector, For example sector 11.
flashAdd1 = 0x81C0010 //sector11
flashAdd2 = 0x81C0020 //sector11
flashAdd3 = 0x81C0030.//sector11
Or use three different sector and flash address, sector 9 10 and 11. 
flashAdd1 = 0x81C0010 //sector11
flashAdd2 = 0x8180010 //sector10
flashAdd3 = 0x8140010.//sector 9
Which one is useful ?
My write function first unlocks flash then erases sector, then program flash  and locks flash . And it works.
When I use the same sector ,  program saves only my last change  because of erasing all sector in every
change. for example when I update Ip address, gateway and subnetmask value are erased. 
When I tried using different sector address, it does not work
each time effectively(because of erasing sector time ) I send data to device with an opcode by packet sender terminal. 
  Program size is about 44 kbytes.
Could you advise me anything.
Thanks.

Comment: Erase the area and write the pieces one at a time without additional erase, or back up the pieces you already have in RAM and rewrite them.  Since these three values are so linked maybe you should put them in the same packet anyway.

Comment: Thanks Cris, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/265750)